# Calculate probability that a randomly chosen student is learning 3 languages

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

There are $25$ students in one class. $10$ of them are studying English, $12$ French, $16$ German. $6$ are studying both English and French, $7$ are studying English and German and $5$ are studying French and German.

We choose one student randomly. What is the probability that they are studying all $3$ languages?

I tried it like this:

A - students that are studying English

B - students that are studying French

C - students that are studying German

$P(A \cap B \cap C) = 
1-P(A^c\cup B^c\cup C^c)=
1-[P(A^c\cup B^c)+P(C^{c})-P((A^c\cup B^c)\cap C^c)] = 
1-[P((A\cap B)^c)+P(C^{c})-(1-P((A\cap B)\cup C))]$

But now I don't know what to do with $P((A\cap B)\cup C))$. If I do the union thing again I will just be back at the beginning.

Comment: This seems to be an "inclusion/exclusion" problem.  The standard formula for two events is $P[A \cup B] = P[A] + P[B] - P[A \cap B]$.  There is a related formula for $P[A \cup B \cup C]$.

Comment: That solved it.

Comment: Good.  If you like you can then answer your own question and vote that as the best answer, which is standard practice when solving a question based on hints.

Answer (score 0):

Draw a Venn diagram. For the triple intersection put in your unknown a. 
Now as EUF=6, for EUFUG' put in 6-a.
In similar fashion, FUGUE'=5-a; & EUGUF'=7-a.

But now, EUF'UG' becomes 10-[6+(7-a)]; FUE'UG'=12-[6+(5-a)]; & GUE'UF'=16-[5+(7-a)].

But now we have a problem: is it assumed that everyone in the class is taking at least one language?! For o/w we have 2 unknowns where a+b=5.

If all are taking at least one, then a=5, & the probability will be 5/25=1/5.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.